# Visualforce email template : how to add an email by default on CC or BCC fields?

Tags: visualforce

I created an email template and would like to know if it 's possible to add a specific email address by default on cc or bcc fields when the users send the email ?

[image]

at the top of the code :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
<messaging:emailTemplate
```

recipientType="Contact"

relatedToType="BC__c"
subject= "FUN {!relatedTo.FUN_BC__c} - 
{!relatedTo.Sales_Order__r.Name } - 
{!relatedTo.Name} - 
({!relatedTo.Shipping_mode__c}) ">

thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your code as text.  It is difficult to read code in an image.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an Email template, including VF email templates do not define the recipients.

Recipients are defined either in:

- An Email Alert (Flow, process Builder, Workflow Rule)
- Apex method calls on [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm?search_text=setToAddresses)
- The send email action/buttons in the UI

This is an example of a separation of concerns pattern - the template defines the content, and other layers define the when and where of the email action.